# Positioning labels in a way that they don't touch each other donutplot matplotlib pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

The labels of the middle donut touch each other.
How to make sure that labels are in the middle of the part they belong to but don't touch each other?

Making the figure bigger doesn't help and changing the labeldistance doesn't change the distance between the labels but the position in the figure.

```
df1   = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz', 'baz'], 
                  'group2': ['one cs', 'two s', 'one cs', 'two seds', 'three fe', 'four cs'],
                  'count': [15,19,14,1,2,1]})
outside = df1.groupby('group1')['count'].sum()
middle =  df1.groupby(['group1','group2'])['count'].sum()

plt.pie(outside, startangle=90, labels=outside.index,textprops=dict(color="black"), pctdistance=0.90 )

plt.pie(middle, labeldistance=0.75, radius=0.75, labels=middle.reset_index().iloc[:,1], startangle=90,   textprops=dict(color="black") )

centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.5,color='black', fc='white',linewidth=0)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166508/change-autopct-label-position-on-matplotlib-pie-chart):

```
patches, texts = plt.pie(middle, labeldistance=0.75, radius=0.75, labels=middle.reset_index().iloc[:,1], startangle=90,   textprops=dict(color="black") )
```

And add this part before `plt.show()`

```
for patch, txt in zip(patches, texts):
    # the angle at which the text is located
    ang = (patch.theta2 + patch.theta1) / 2.
    # new coordinates of the text, 0.7 is the distance from the center
    x = patch.r * 0.7 * np.cos(ang*np.pi/180)
    y = patch.r * 0.8 * np.sin(ang*np.pi/180)
    # if patch is narrow enough, move text to new coordinates
    if (patch.theta2 - patch.theta1) < 10.:
        txt.set_position((x, y))
```